# jquery onclick not responding in android tablet

Tags: android, jquery, html

My image-slider code is perfectly working pc ,ipad but on tablet onclick event is not working. when i used .on and print something with alert then onclick works. if i am replacing alert with console.log then it's not working .

i don't understand why is this happening ?

```
 $('#myImageFlow').on("touchstart click",".sliderImage", function(event)
        {


                //alert('i am on method  '+event.type);
                console.log('on method ==='+event.type);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply: console.log is browser-related and you have no way to know if it will work or not (console is browser-dependant). Use other method to log (alert is ok in debug time imho)

Comment: instead of alert what should i use .. i dont want to print any thing .on i am just writting because of that click works in tablet

Answer (score 0):

try to use tap event of jquery instead of click.